# Internal static array (K&R month_name() function)

Tags: c

In K&R section 5.8, there is a function month_name() which uses an internal static char pointer array, and makes a point to mention that this is an "ideal application for an internal static array."  The function is below:

```
/* month_name: return name of n-th month */
char *month_name(int n)
{
    static char *name[] = {
        "Illegal month",
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December"
    };
    return (n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
}
```

My understanding is that `static` when applied to internal variable means that the variable hangs around after function returns, and still exists for the next time the function is entered.  So the only theory I could come up for why `static` is used here, is that maybe if static wasn't used, the char *name[] would be re-initialized every single time the function was entered, which would be inefficient.  I did try the function with the `static` keyword removed, and it still seemed to work fine.  So I wanted to test my theory that maybe the array was being created more than once.  I created this test, which may be totally worthless, but it's the best I could come up with:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string
    printf("%d\n", month_name(1)); // print address of string
    printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string
    printf("%d\n", month_name(1)); // print address of string
}
```

My theory was that if the string array was being duplicated inefficiently, the address would change for the second function call... but it remained the same.  So I even went a step further and tried to initialize another character array just to shift the allocation a bit (again, this may be totally worthless based on my limited knowledge of how allocation works):

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string
    printf("%d\n", month_name(1)); // print address of string
    char dummy[] = "dummy";
    printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string
    printf("%d\n", month_name(1)); // print address of string
}
```

But, the address of "January" is still the same for both function calls, even with the char *name[] in the month_name function NOT being declared as `static`.

So... couple questions.

1) What is the point of it being static?  Why is it an ideal application for internal static array?

2) Is there any merit to the logic behind my test above?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that your compiler optimizes code my making this array static, even if you didn't write it explicitly. Try turning off optimizations and see what happens.

Comment: "static when applied to internal variable means that the variable hangs around after function returns, and still exists for the next time the function is entered" - That is true. This is done to make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not `static` it's on the stack. Since the function is returning a `char *` pointer to it, that's kind of important and it needs to be done that way.

If it's not `static`, outside of the function you have a pointer to a stack variable that is no longer valid. Your "test" isn't showing this because the memory hasn't yet been reused. Make no mistake - it will be at some point.

**Edit:** Jim brings up a good point in the comments below that I didn't think about initially. Since these are string literals, they are already in read-only memory. I *think* that using `static` here simply keeps from re-initializing the `char *name[]` array each time.  The initial answer above does apply to other data types, but in this case I don't think it does.

Comment: So basically I could be pointing to something that doesn't exist anymore after the function exits?  So the main concern is not wasting space (as I thought), but actually using space which will remain consistent until you need it?

Comment: In this case, without static, wouldn't only the array of pointers be on the stack? Wouldn't the actual text always be in the same memory?

Comment: Correct - once you leave the function, if it is not `static` you have a pointer to something that no longer exists. It doesn't have anything to do with wasting space but rather actually having a valid pointer.

Comment: Thanks.  It's a shame K&R don't seem to explain stack/heap at all.  I have a very shaky understanding of it from the limited explanations I've read on the internet.  It really seems like you can't understand C language without understanding underlying memory usage better... and from asking around it sounds as though I will need to read a book on compiler design to really get a handle on that.

Comment: @JimRhodes - you know, that's an interesting point. Because they're string literals ... the addresses should be fixed and read-only. I didn't think of that. In that case it's just a simple case of only wanting to initialized them once.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an invalid test.
You are not printing the address of `name` array, but the address of the string literal which is always "January".

Note that `name` is not an array of characters where you return the address to the portion inside it, but it is an array of pointers to string literals.

Therefore, what is initialized each time you enter a function is `name` array, not the literals which are constant by their nature.

EDIT: another thing is that the compiler is quite an intelligent beast. Thus, even if you print out the value of `name` array, you will get the same address (thanks to inlining, most probably), however GCC compiler at Mac seems to get fooled with an indirect call (`gcc -O0` call). Test the following code:

```
char *month_name(int n)
{
  static char *name[] = {
    "Illegal month",
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December"
  };
  printf("names addr = %p\n", name);
  return (n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
}

void indirect_call_function(char* (*fptr)(int n))
{
  fptr(1);
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string

  indirect_call_function(month_name);

  char dummy[] = "dummy";

  printf("%s\n", month_name(1)); // print string
}
```

Compare to the code with static `name`.

Comment: PS: you should use %p to display an address of string.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems similar to what Dave showed me below.  The salient point is that the address you are printing is name and not name[1]... so you're printing the location of the pointer array rather than the location of the "January" string.  Removing the 'static' in your code will cause different addresses to be printed, but if you also replace name with name[1] in the print line, then the same address is printed no matter what. I never knew string literals acted like that. It is almost as if they are all global and static? And the compiler will re-use "January" rather than make a new one?

Comment: Yes. It seems me and Dave made the same analysis and responded around the same time. Yes, I'm printing name, because as I pointed out the name array is what is allocated from scratch each time function enters - not the individual string literals in it. Yes, you are right, compilers go through all the literals they find in the code and put them into .data section as Dave has already pointed out and then replace their occurrences in code with this address. (at least, conceptually, it's what happens)

Answer (score 1):

The point of it being static is exactly what you stated. It means the array is initialised *once and once only.*

An "internal" static (as you put it) has visibility of the current function and duration for the entire program execution. Another way of doing this would be to use a global (file-level) variable but that has the disadvantage of being visible outside the function.

And, yes, your test is flawed. Even *if* the address of the array on the stack changed (and it probably doesn't since you're calling `month_name` from the same stack level each time), the actual *characters themselves* are not usually on the stack (assuming your implementation even *has* a stack). They're string literals and will probably be stored in the code section at a specific location.

By adding more string literals, you may cause their address to change but that's by no means guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the array was being re-initalized, the address of the strings would be the same each time; The address of a string literal is usually the same, because it resides in the (read-only) .data section; although technically, `"a" == "a"` is undefined behavior. What static prevents, is the recreation of the array, such that this:

```
char* month_static(int n){
   static char * months[] = {  /*month names*/ };
   printf("static: %p\n", months);
   return months[n];
}
char* month_nonstatic(int n){ 
   char * months[] = {  /*month names*/ };
   printf("nonstatic: %p\n", months);
   return months[n];
}
void large_ar(char*(*fn)(int), int n){
   int ints[50000];
   fn(n);
}
int main(){
   month_static(3);
   month_nonstatic(3);
   large_ar(month_static, 3);
   large_ar(month_nonstatic, 3);
}
```

outputs:

```
static: 0x80497f0
nonstatic: 0xbfd11a10
static: 0x80497f0
nonstatic: 0xbfce0cb0
```

You'll notice that the static calls print the same address, while the nonstatic ones change.

Comment: I think this is probably a really good explanation, but I must be missing something.  First, I never knew that a string literal always had the same address.  But isn't month[3] the address to the same string literal in each function (for example, "March")?  So how did your little ints[50000] trick cause us to get a different address for "March", if string literals always have the same address?  Color me confused still. :-/

Comment: Ok, nevermind... I just realized that your printf lines are printing months and not months[_].  So I get what you are showing me, which is that the actual array gets re-created in non-static case but not in static case.  But if I do replace "months" with "months[3]" in the printf lines, then the output is the same address printed 4 times, which proves that months[3] (aka "March") is ALWAYS at the same address no matter what.  Again, this is totally new to me and kind of crazy.  So every time you create a string literal, the compiler checks to make sure it doesn't already exist?

Comment: It usually does, but it's technically undefined behavior. I'll clarify that in the answer

Comment: Nevertheless, it sounds like you understand what's going on.